# Cannot build on debug mode but can build release

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, build, release

I try to build a dll and get the error:

```
Could not copy the file "path\of\app\bin\Debug\SharpPlink-Win32.svnExe"  
because it was not found. (MSB3030)
```

When I try to build on release mode, everything is correct.

Any ideas?

Comment: you are missing this file

Comment: @lordkain, What can I do then?

Comment: i dont know SharpPlink, but probally locate the debug version or link to the release version

Comment: @lordkain, Thanks. I copied the missing file from the Release folder to the debug. Please post it as answer so that I could accept it.

Comment: np, glad I could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i dont know SharpPlink, but probally locate the debug version or link to the release version